# Wildcard/regex mapping in requirejs

Tags: javascript, regex, requirejs, amd

Is there a way do do wildcard/regex mapping in requirejs? Something like this:

```
{
    map: {
        'controllers/.+' : {
            'controllers/(.+)' : 'notAllowedModuleThatThrowsError$1', //$1 is capture group if wanted
        }
    }
}
```

I basically want this as the example show, to enforce a good structure (MVC or otherwise) in my application I want to prevent certain modules from getting access to certain other modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such support for this in RequireJS right now. In case you wonder, the `"*"` notation is not handled through pattern matching.